# Blender - move camera each rendered frame for mono font

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

For my game, i need to render all chars from a mono type font, where all symbols are the same width and height.
So, i think to type them in a long string against X axis, and move a camera over each symbol to get rendered frames.
Later i will compile these frames with metadata to larger map.
Well, can i execute a script, which will modify a scene by the render trigger or something ?

Thanks !

Comment: How about using keyframes?

Comment: Seems the only way :) Just generated about thousand by the script

Answer (score 0):

Implemented it by a script, which generates keyframes for a camera, thousand of them.
Here is the blender file [https://yadi.sk/d/6AXRNZDxEwAtDw](http://Mono%20font%20(Courier%20New)%20to%20images)

And here is the code, note these magic numbers - i was finding them for few hours, and still not sure if they are right, but close

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

# useful shortcut
scene = bpy.context.scene

# this shows you all objects in scene
scene.objects.keys()
cam = bpy.data.objects["Camera"];
cam.location.x = 0
for frame in range(1073):
    scene.frame_set(frame)
    cam.location.x = frame * 0.35285 - 0.209;
    cam.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", index=-1)
```